# How do I reinstall package "mount"?

Tags: mount

When trying to update, use software center, install via apt-get in terminal, open synaptic package manager I get an error that reads "The package mount needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." How can I reinstall the package if none of the instillation apts can mount the file systems to install the broken package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify your version, I'll assume you're on 14.04.

There's a package called *mount* in trusty: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mount

Try to open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install mount`.

If all else fails, you can download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/mount/download) and install it manually using `dpkg -i mount_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20_i386.deb`.

Comment: The dpkg -i thing worked. The only difference was I was on a 64 bit computer so had to use the amd64 package instead of the i386 but I had already found it so that wasn't a problem. Thanks for the quick response. I'll mark this solved.

Comment: @JeffKlein to mark it as solved, plase [click on the checkmark](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) on the left.